# PyCharm fails to connect to the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I tried to run a python script from PyCharm.

It shows that PyCharm is connecting to the console, and it stays like this forever.

[image]

In the task-manager window, I see that the process is running:

[image]

I also see the following error message:

```
C:\git\heca_v2\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=53025
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 33, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle.pydev_console_utils import BaseInterpreterInterface
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_thrift
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pydev_console.pydev_protocol import DebugValue, GetArrayResponse, ArrayData, ArrayHeaders, ColHeader, RowHeader, \
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydev_console\pydev_protocol.py", line 6, in <module>
    _console_thrift = _shaded_thriftpy.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "console.thrift"),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\__init__.py", line 29, in load
    thrift = parse(path, module_name, include_dirs=include_dirs,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 502, in parse
    parser.parse(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 1106, in parseopt_notrack
    p.callable(pslice)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 212, in p_struct
    val = _fill_in_struct(p[1], p[3])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 765, in _fill_in_struct
    gen_init(cls, thrift_spec, default_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 103, in gen_init
    cls.__init__ = init_func_generator(default_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\_compat.py", line 123, in init_func_generator
    new_code = types.CodeType(*args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: code() argument 13 must be str, not int
Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What version of python are you using? And you might wanna update PyCharm to the latest version.

Comment: @Ovski, Python 3.10, PyCharm 2020.

Comment: I do see your Pycharm version in your error message, that is why I suggested to update to current version 2022.2.5. Is something preventing you from updating your PyCharm installation?

Comment: @Ovski, *Is something preventing you from updating your PyCharm installation?* --- For some reason later versions are giving me java launch error.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but is it possible that you have multiple versions of JDKs and/or JREs installed? It's hard to tell if your problem is based on your Python environment or your PyCharm installation. I would probably begin with cleaning up my Java environment and reinstalling PyCharm. Are you able to run other projects? Maybe just recreate the venv of this current project?

Comment: @Ovski, *Are you able to run other projects?* --- No.

Comment: @Ovski, *is it possible that you have multiple versions of JDKs and/or JREs installed?* --- Negative. PyCharm is running on bundled java.